# Is this syntactically correct C code?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I am just starting to learn C and am bit confused about use of return statement and its importance in C language.

Here's my code snippet. Is this syntactically correct or do we have to return any numerical value 0 or 1 while using int main()?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i;


        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
              printf("\n Noooooooooo");

        return ;      
 }
```

Comment: IMO, it is *semantically* wrong.(and: it should *at least* be`int main(void){...}`

Comment: If the compiler does not complain about syntax errors, then it is syntactically correct C. whether it is semantically correct, or makes any sense is another question.

Comment: For `main()` it's either all or nothing. Just `return` without argument is none of them.

Comment: @alk and others, that does not make it syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I didn't say or meant to imply this.

Comment: For any function you declare as returning an `int`, the `return` statement must return an `int` expression. You can only use a `return` statement without an expression if the function is declared as `void`.

Comment: @DavidRTribble: The expression in the `return` does not need to be an `int` expression. It needs to be assignable to an `int`. 6.8.6.4 3 says the value is converted as if by assignment. For example, the expression in the `return` statement could be a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Per the C 2011 standard (draft N1570), clause 6.8.6.4, paragraph 1:

> A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

Your return statement does not have an expression and appears in the `main` function whose return type is `int`, not `void`. Hence your program violates the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's clarify that because you refer to the `main` function, obviously (but not for all seems) this answer assume that you are referring to an **hosted environment**, because for a **freestanding environment** (see **ISO/IEC 9899:2011** "**§5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment**") there are no requirements at all and **the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined**.

Going back to the **hosted environment**, the standard that defines C language, in its more recent version **ISO/IEC 9899:2011**, for C11, describe the requirements for the program startup function in an enough strict way (**§5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**).

The points to be respected are essentially:

- The `main` function **must return an `int`**.
- Only 2 variation of it are allowed:

  1. Without parameters as in : `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
  2. With 2 parameters a count of argument elements and the array of arguments as in : `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

Some implementation variation are allowed, but only as different representation of same parameters (i.e. instead of `char *argv[]` the equivalent `char **argv`, or some `typedef` for specific types resolving in an `int` type for `argc`).

The very common definition `void main() { /* ... */ }` allowed in some major compiler producers (most often MS) **are not strictly C99-C11 compliant**.

In fact the use of empty parenthesis in function declarators is an obsolescent feature that could be removed in future standard revision as reported in "**§6.11 Future language directions**" (thanks to have reported me the imprecision). In fact many compilers C99-C11 compliant issue a warning.

So considering the before mentioned obsolescence would be a good habit to use a more standard declarations.

In conclusion your declaration is wrong because:

1. `return;` You return no value
2. Optionally consider that `main()` miss the `void` (strict C99-C11)

What you return depends on what you want return. Let only say that a general convention commonly accepted is to return from main the value `0` (zero) for normal termination (no errors), any other value denotes an execution error.

Anyway for the sake of precision, for those who want go inside specs, I report below the exact text from specific paragraph

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> The function called at program startup is named main.
>   The implementation declares no prototype for this
>   function. It **shall be defined with a return type of int** (emphasis mine, please see below the definition of the term **shall** in ISO document) and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ } or with two parameters
> ```
>
> (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as
>   they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;(see note below) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

The note for equivalent type says:

> **NOTE:** Thus, int can be replaced by a `typedef` name defined as **`int`**, or the type of `argv` can be written as `char ** argv`, and so on

Last to remove any doubt about the meaning of the term "**shall**" the **ISO/IEC 9899:2011** specification clearly define it on paragraph **§4.0 Conformance at subpar. 1**:

> **4.0 Conformance**
>
> **1** In this International Standard, ‘‘**shall**’’ is to be interpreted as
>   **a  requirement** on an implementation or on a program; conversely,
>   ‘‘shall not’’ is to be interpreted as a prohibition.

Comment: "The main function must return an int" - stated that absolutely is plain wrong as the rest about the signature. It is not even exactly correct for a hosted environment. For a freestanding, it completely depends on the environment. Additioinally, a function definition may use empty parenteses for an empty parameter list. It is not disallowed, but just an obsolescent feature (see 6.11.6).